# How to use window.open to open a controller action in the same window in jquery in mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my jquery code, I can open a new action using the following code:

```
window.open("ControllerAction");
```

However, this opens the controller action in a different tab. How can I make this open in the same window without creating a separate tab.

This is basically a workaround I have found to doing page refresh in asp.net mvc.

Comment: You should use `window.location.href = "/{controller}/{action}";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Window.location`

> Though Window.location is a read-only Location object, you can also assign a DOMString to it. This means that you can work with location as if it were a string in most cases: location = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of location.href = 'http://www.example.com'

Basically you can use one of these, `assign()` and `replace()` navigates to the URL without adding a new record to the history. Here you find more: [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```
var url = "/{controller}/{action}";
window.location.href = url;
window.location.assign(url);
window.location = url;
window.location.replace =url;
```

instead

```
window.open("ControllerAction");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for anyone who searched but I got it to work. Below code works.

```
window.location.replace("ControllerAction");
```